# Convert array to comma separated values

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I'm using PHP.

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[home] => 9
[pets] => 8
[dogs] => 7
[shampoo] => 7
[cover] => 6
)
```

I want to create a comma separated list which is:

```
home,pets,dogs,shampoo,cover
```

Here's what I'm trying but giving me blank string (`$words` is the array):

```
$myWords = implode(',',$words[0]);
```

Do I need to loop instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're close. You just need the keys from that array. [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/array_keys) will do that for you:

```
 $myWords = implode(',',array_keys($words));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = implode(',', array_keys($words));
```

`$words[0]` does not exist in your array, because all of your keys are strings.